# GDAL VRT files get corrupted by reading

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, vrt

In my stand-alone QGIS app I am using vrt files of DTED rasters. **All** vrt files are build with the same Python code and have the same structure, codepage etc. I use them for display only.

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="121" rasterYSize="121">
  <SRS>GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform> 4.0995833333333330e+001, 8.3333333333333003e-003, 0.0000000000000000e+000, 2.7004166666666666e+001, 0.0000000000000000e+000,-8.3333333333333003e-003</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int16" band="1">
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">1401</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">1000.386039205</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">818</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">97.464262339239</MDI>
    </Metadata>
    <NoDataValue>-3.27670000000000E+004</NoDataValue>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">DTED/E041/N26.dt0</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="121" RasterYSize="121" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="1" BlockYSize="121" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="121" ySize="121" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="121" ySize="121" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

It happens, that **some** vrt files get changed in the way, that the line `<GeoTransform>...</GeoTransform>` is deleted! And sometimes in the lines beginning with `<MDI` the decimal dot is changed to a comma. Both happen independently from another.

This is true for only some vrt files, but when it happens then always the same files are affected. I pasted the missing line back into the vrt files (or build them new), and after some QGIS ups and downs, the same effect takes place.

I am having this problem with QGIS 2.8.2 on CentOs 7 using German language settings. Any ideas what's going on here? Or what additional information I should supply to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Following environment variable solved the problem:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`

Btw this also solved a problem with spatial queries against SpatiaLite databases, where in sqlite3_prepare statements a mixture of decimal point and comma occur.